# Infotec's Web Builder is not displaying Excel content

Tags: content-management-system

I changed an `Archive Content` resource with a `archivo.pdf` file for a file  `archivo 1.xls` and the iframe shows Web Builder's 404 default error page.

The same page is shown when clicking the resource from the administration.

Comment: Can somebody add the tag web-builder-cms please?

Answer (score 0):

When files contain blanks (white spaces, \r etc) and non ASCII characters this is what happends, just change the name of the file and it will be accesible.